# How to make right function?

Tags: c, max, min, conditional-operator, function-definition

```
#include<stdio.h>
int CompareNumber(int n1,int n2,int n3 )
{
    int a = (n1 < n2) ? n2 : n1;
    int b = (a < n3) ? n3 : a;
    int c = (n1 > n2) ? n2 : n1;
    int d = (c > n3) ? n3 : c;
    printf("biggest %d smallest %d", a, d);
    return 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;
    scanf_s("%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c);
    CompareNumber(a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

*when I enter 5,6,7, this code prints 5 for the biggest number, and some meaningless number for the smallest number*

Comment: Better variable names could help -- the biggest number is `b`, not `a`. Have you entered the commas in the input and verified that the input was read properly, perhaps by echoing the input?

Comment: `b` is defined but not used in `CompareNumber`. Show the exact output you are getting.

Comment: omg very thank you I didn't enter the commas...

Answer (score 1):

Change this statement

```
printf("biggest %d smallest %d", a, d);
```

to

```
printf("biggest %d smallest %d", b, d);
```

because the maximum value is stored in the variable `b`.

Also this call

```
scanf_s("%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c);
```

requires from the user to enter also commas. Change it to

```
scanf_s("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
```

Pay attention to that using non-meaningfull names of variables as a, b, c, d makes the code unreadable. Also the return type of the function does not make a sense.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
void CompareNumber( int n1, int n2, int n3 )
{
    int max = ( n1 < n2 ) ? n2 : n1;
    max = ( max < n3 ) ? n3 : max;
    
    int min = ( n2 < n1) ? n2 : n1;
    min = ( n3 < min ) ? n3 : min;
    
    printf( "biggest %d smallest %d", max, min );
}
```

And even better when the function does one thing: determines the minimum and the maximum values and return them to the caller and it is the caller that outputs the result.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Pair
{
    int min;
    int max;
};

struct Pair  CompareNumber( int n1, int n2, int n3 )
{
    struct Pair p = { n2 < n1 ? n2 : n1, n1 < n2 ? n2 : n1 };
    
    p.min = n3 < p.min ? n3 : p.min;
    p.max = p.max < n3 ? n3 : p.max;
    
    return p;    
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
 
    struct Pair p = CompareNumber( a , b,  c );
    
    printf( "biggest %d smallest %d", p.max, p.min );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
biggest 7 smallest 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing `a` with the third variable. Here's a simpler representation of `CompareNumber`:

```
int CompareNumber(int n1,int n2,int n3 )
{
    int a = (n1 < n2) ? n2 : n1;
    a = (a < n3) ? n3 : a;

    int d = (n1 < n2) ? n1 : n2;
    d = (d < n3) ? d : n3;

    printf("biggest %d smallest %d", a, d);
    return 0;
}
```

Your `main` function should be fixed like suggested in other posts.

... and here's a better (for me) alternative:

```
int max (int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

int min (int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? b : a;
}

int CompareNumber(int n1,int n2,int n3 )
{
    int a = max (max (n1, n2), n3);
    int d = min (min (n1, n2), n3);

    printf("biggest %d smallest %d", a, d);
    return 0;
}
```